# Trying to pass a string for querying through Django Rest Framework urls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have a django project and I am using Django Rest Frameowkr. I setup up a model, serializer, view, and url for a users model. I have the urls file. I want to passing in something like a username when the api url is called. I currently have it setup to have a primary key so when I enter a primary key it works. I want to switch it to username. I also want the serializer query to return the user object iwth the usename I pass in. 
I am using Djangos standard `User` object from `django.contrib.auth.models` 
Here is the code I have

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .views import UserListView, UserDetailsView
from .views import ProfileListView, ProfileDetailsView
from .views import RoleListView, RoleDetailsView

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', UserListView.as_view()),
    path('user/<pk>', UserDetailsView.as_view()),
]
```

serializer.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile, Role

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
```

Views.py file

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from users.models import Profile, Role
from .serializers import UserSerializer, ProfileSerializer, RoleSerializer

class UserListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the **`lookup_field`** in `UserDetailsView` and change the urls pattern in `urls.py` as below

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/', UserListView.as_view()),
    path('user/<username>', UserDetailsView.as_view()),
]


# views.py
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

Comment: it worked but i have another question. lets say that i want to do the same thing but find the username in a user that is a foriegnkey to another table. User is the foriegnkey to another model. I wnt to the take that username from the url and do the lookup inside that foriegnkey. @JPG

Comment: I won't recommend **nested lookup**, because it will take time (in the background, Django joins the relevant tables)

Comment: If you want to do, **`currentfield__username`** in `lookup_field`

Comment: so if I had this... it shoudl work. `class ProfileDetailsView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'` or should i do it without the quotes around user__username. there is a table called Profile that has a user foriegnkey